# Reduce number of calls to database when creating objects?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So, im not-quite-newbie at sql but i am still learning. The situation is that i have the following code:

```
Thread thread = context.Threads
                .Where(t => t.ThreadId == id)
                .Include(p => p.Posts)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (thread != null) {

                foreach (var item in thread.Posts) {
                    UserProfile profile = new UserProfile();
                    profile.UserId = item.CreatedBy;
                    profile.UserName = userManager.FindById(profile.UserId).UserName;
                    item.UserProfile = profile;
                }
            }
```

The code i have works without problem, it fetches all the related post to the thread, but a thread with 50 posts would make 50 queries to make a userprofile and that seem very inefficient. Is there anyway i can improve this to make fewer queries and still create a UserProfile for each post?

I've disabled lazy loading if that makes any difference.

Comment: @RaymondNijland no they *don't*. That's the dreaded N+1 problem. The solution is to NOT make 50 queries, eg by using `FindById`.

Comment: @Gixen *don't* make 50 queries - don't use `FindById`. ORMs work by mapping *relations* - there should be a relation between Posts and users, eg a `Post.User` property. This would allow the *ORM* to generate the SQL query that would load user names along with posts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your right mine explainment was totally wrong.. i really need some coffee just woke up..

Comment: @Gixen a Post's *author* may be the same *real person* as a *login user* but that doesn't mean you need to load the user name from the *authentication system*. You don't have to load the *username* from the authentication provider. What if you used Google? Besides, how often will the *author* of a post change? How often will a *login name* change? Perhaps you should store the `author` as a separate string property when creating the `Post` instance.

Comment: "ORMs work by mapping relations - there should be a relation between Posts and users, eg a Post.User property. This would allow the ORM to generate the SQL query that would load user names along with posts" Yes some ORM generate multiple (SELECT without JOIN) SQL queries to map the relations and some ORM generate correct JOIN statement to map the relation depening on how the ORM is programmed or settings like lazy loading @PanagiotisKanavos this is what i was trying to tell in mine first (deleted) comment..

Comment: @RaymondNijland both EF and NHibernate will create joins in this case - one Post has one Author.

Comment: @Gixen another option could be to create a separate `Author` class that maps to the same table as a user, or to a view that only returns the fields needed for the `Author` entity. This would allow the ORM to create a proper JOIN between posts and user without forcing you to request individual author entities

Comment: "both EF and NHibernate will create joins in this case - one Post has one Author." i was talking about ORM's in general sense not programming language specific..  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @RaymondNijland then you are talking about microORMs

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you all for your quick answers! They provided me with some good knowledge on how to handle queries to the database. 
As per both @Raymond and @Panagiotis insights i mapped the UserProfile class to a table that stores the id and name of a user. Further i added a UserProfile to the Post class.

Then by changing my query to the following and deleting the foreach loop:

```
Thread thread = context.Threads
                .Include(p => p.Posts)
                .Include(p => p.Posts.Select(e => e.UserProfile))
                .Where(t => t.ThreadId == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

It then queried the UserProfiles and mapping it to the Post.UserProfile and reduced the N-calls to 1. Yay!